# What group action has $\forall x,y,\exists g:g\cdot x=g\cdot y$?

Tags: group-theory, functions, group-actions

Consider the action of $G$ on $X$.

Let it be a property of $G,X$ that $\forall x,y,\exists g:g\cdot x=g\cdot y$.  This is not quite a transitive action - it describes for example a sequence of inclusions.  **What is the name for this type of action?**  I can't pair it with an appropriate definition from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action_(mathematics)#Types_of_actions).

My attempt?  There seem to be several things going on here, none of which I can associate with documented group theory at the moment.

$G$ seems to define a "contracting epimorphism"

$G$ seems to define the identity function on the trivial group having the powerset of $X$ as its element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No group action (on a set with more than one element) satisfies this. If $g\cdot x=g\cdot y$, then $x=g^{-1}\cdot(g\cdot x)=g^{-1}\cdot(g\cdot y)=y$, so your condition implies $x=y$ for all $x,y\in X$.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to correspond to my suggestion that it's the identity function on the trivial group.

Answer (score 3):

This is only possibly if $X$ is a singleton (or, vacuously, if $X$ is empty). To see this: let $x, y \in X$ and suppose $g$ is such that $g \cdot x = g \cdot y$. Then $x = g^{-1}g \cdot x = g^{-1}g \cdot y = y$. So all elements in $X$ are equal, and thus $X$ is a singleton . It is not hard to see that if $X$ is a singleton, this property holds.

Since this property can only hold in uninteresting cases, I doubt it has a name.

Comment: I think the name of this group action might be the identity function on the trivial group then?

Comment: @user334732 The group itself need not be trivial, the set $X$ is trivial. On a singleton every group can have only one action. So you could call it "the canonical/trivial action on the singleton", but that's more a description than a name (and a lot of words for something trivial).

Comment: Fabulous, that clears up the thing I was unclear on. In my case the group is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$ and I was struggling to reconcile this with the structure of the set $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, notice that $g^{-1}\cdot (g\cdot x) = (g^{-1}g)\cdot x = 1\cdot x = x$.

Thus $g\cdot x = g\cdot y$ implies by applying $g^{-1}$ that $x=y$.